# How to write jQuery animate when adding height

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height

```
CSS   
.bxspace{height: 258px;}    

jQuery
$('.bxspace').height( $('.bxspace').height() + 15 );
```

This is my code with the function to get the `bxspace` height and add `15px` when click. But I want to apply animate() to move it smoothly when adding `15px`. Tried below qjQuery but not working.

```
var height = $('.bxspace').height( $('.bxspace').height() + 15 ); 
$('.bxspace').animate({height: height+'px'});
```

I'm newbie in jQuery and I'm not sure how to combine both of these code. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use incremental syntax in `animate()` for properties that accept numeric values

Try:

```
$('.bxspace').animate({height: "+=15"});
```

Comment: I see, didn't think about this method. It's works. Thanks.